# Mipmap folder missing Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have create Android project on Android Studio. But there is no mipmap folder for placing app icons.

[image]

Does that mean that I have to create mipmap folder ? Or is there something wrong with project setup ?

Comment: What version of Android Studio do you have? Only Android Studio 1.1+ will create these folders automatically. It will work fine if you create the folders yourself.

Comment: @BrentM : Android Studio 1.1.0.

Comment: That's strange, I get the folder created for every new project even when targeting API as old as gingerbread. Maybe try recreating the project, or just add the folders manually.

Comment: you can just create it, not such big deal

Answer (score 1):

If you have existing mipmap folder, backup it up first.

1) Right click on res folder in android studio.

2) New > Android resource directory

3) In directory name, enter mipmap; resource type select mipmap, source set remain as main

4) click ok

Copy the previously backed up folders and paste it into the res folder. The mipmap folder will then auto update to the folders you copied into it.

Answer (score 0):

The mipmap folder holds the icon image for your apps launcher. These should be only as large as necessary to support the devices you want to target for your app. If mipmap is absent from your project, you can add it:

Right-click the res folder
Choose New
Choose Android Resource Directory
Name the directory :- mipmap
In the Resource Types Section add mipmap
Click ok